# Unable to enter recovery mode on Ubuntu MATE

Tags: ubuntu, password, recovery

I forgot my password for Ubuntu MATE and I've read that the only way to reset it in Ubuntu is to enter recovery mode and enter a root shell etc. The problem is, I can't figure out how to enter recovery mode. <kbd>Shift</kbd> never works when I hold it down (it works when typing etc.) and I can't use `sudo` to, for example, force recovery mode to boot by modifying `recovery.cmdline`. I do have auto-login set, so I can still use the OS, but some stuff I'm doing requires `sudo`, therefore I need to reset/recover my password.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to enter recovery mode."* -> That's not the only solution, presuming you can take the SD card out and access the root filesystem, e.g. from another linux box.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168422/25985 -> Same logic applies to all user accounts.

Comment: OK, this solves my problem with the password, but I still can't enter recovery mode. I'd like to be able to.

Comment: How would I go about mounting the root partition? My Mac doesn't show any additional partitions.